# Gorilla Mux Router : Enforce auth is enabled by default for all routes

Tags: go, authentication, gorilla

Is there a way to enforce that Authentication is enabled by default in Gorilla mux router. The intent is to make sure a dev, while adding a new API, does not forget to add auth.

We can always write a wrapper function (over router.Handle()) and ask devs to create new routes using that, but is there a better/cleaner way ?

Comment: Write the proposed wrapper function, but wrap the mux instead of the individual handlers.

Comment: may be this is what you are looking for [gorilla-mux-custom-middleware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26204485/gorilla-mux-custom-middleware)